# Greetings for presents and cards

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, saludos

What phrases and greetings can you use for christmas presents / cards? Are there "general purpose" phrases which can be used for presents which are used the whole year, like an iPod?

For example:

- ¡Te deseo lo mejor!
- ¡Muchos saludos!
- ¡Muchos besos!
- Cariños

Comment: Can you provide one or two examples of what you mean in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best catch-all expression is **¡Felicidades!**

It applies to Christmas, New Year, Passover, Eid, birthdays, baptisms, bris, graduations, engagements, weddings, new jobs...

Comment: Or "¡Muchas felicidades!"

Comment: @dusan yes, that's common.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon Why did you delete that? Not everyone knows what Passover is... I added that so people won't have to look for it. :)

Comment: @Alenanno why do you assume most people know what Christmas is and not what Passover is? (Actually, we don't even have to deal with "most" people, only the educated ones that are likely to use this site) Besides, calling it "Jewish easter" is disrespectful.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon There's no need to be harsh. But can you explain why is that disrespectful? I didn't mean to disrespect anything or anyone, of course, and I apologize if I unintentionally did, but maybe you're taking this too much personally.

Comment: @Diego Just add [Eid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_ul-Fitr) and settle it.

Comment: @belisarius done.

Comment: @Alenanno I did not intend to be harsh, but firm (sorry if it came out wrong). It *is* disrespectful because: (1) Passover has nothing to do with Easter (2) It has been celebrated for several more centuries (3) Easter was, for centuries and until very recently, a good excuse to beat up or murder jews, so it's not something we want associated with *our* holiday.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon Oh ok, we're cool then. :)

Comment: @Diego Is this a relative of yours?: http://www.portalguarani.com/autores_detalles.php?id=1096

Comment: @belisarius not that I know...

Answer (score 6):

For Christmas one usually use

> Feliz Navidad [y próspero año nuevo] > Merry Christmas [and a happy new year]

If you don't want to be Christmas specific you can say

> Felices Fiestas > Happy Holidays